# How do I export pictures from LR after deleting originals

Tags: lightroom

I editing some wedding photos in LR, over and over. To eliminate any confusion I deleted my photos off of the computer and before thinking about it I emptied the trash. Now the originals are all gone and of course I cannot export any pictures. I would really like to deliver these photos. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: restore from your backup

Comment: Can't you just copy the pictures off of the sd card or whatever your camera uses? If you don't have a backup of any kind I believe you can export low quality pictures from the generated previews. I don't know much about how you do that other than to say I believe it is possible.

Comment: It will not help you now but in future: that's what labels and stars in LR are made for - label and star your photos and then you can filter your view to see only the photos you want without deleting the others.

Comment: This should be closed as off-topic.  PEBCAK problems have nothing to do with photography.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I disagree. It's about Lightroom and photo recovery.

Comment: @Jeremy it's not about "photo recovery,"  it's about **file** recovery.  Further, it has nothing to do with LR in particular.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft , read rob j crowe's comment above. If the originals are gone he could at the very least recover lower the thumbnails from Lightroom. More than just a camera and editing program are involved in photography.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't restore the originals, you might still be able to [Extract preview for lost images](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/kb/extract-previews-for-lost-images-lightroom.html). But the quality of this depends of course on the previews you had built (minimal..1:1).

Answer (score 0):

Try restoring the originals. Search for programs that can restore files after they have been emptied from the recycle bin/trash. I know they exist but have no experience with them so don't feel confident in recommending any. You can try the same on your camera's memory card.

When a file is deleted it's not usually destroyed, just delisted. If the computer needs space it will overwrite the former file as needed so be quick about trying to restore the files.

This may still be impossible if your computer has a secure delete function enabled. In that case when you empty the trash bin it overwrites the old files with random data do it can't be recovered.

Good luck.

Comment: He didn't specify his OS.  There are similar programs for *nix systems BTW

Comment: True, that was an assumption on my part. Mac OS would be unfortunate because I believe that defaults to secure delete.

Comment: A free, cross-platform program with a long history of saving people's photos is [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec); it works great, but there are probably more user-friendly things available.